# Filter Android Studio Logcat for cordova/phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, logging, phonegap

I am learning cordova/phonegap (particularly for android) and am looking for the best way to log errors and info. I am using Android Studio logcat at the moment, but the problem is that its giving too much info so I am wandering if there any way to filter it to show only phonegap related logs.
Or maybe there is better tools/ways for it (Server Log in phonegap not showing all the logs)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are running a debug application and using the logcat window within Android studio the 2nd drop down from the left at the top of logcat will allow you to filter on the debug application that is running